# jquery cant get element

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is my code which adds class 'nav-pills' to element with class 'nav-tabs' when window width is lower than 768px.

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
$('.nav-tabs').toggleClass('nav-pills', $(window).width() < 768);
});
```

I want to alert something when user click link inside DOM element with these 2 classes (nav-tabs and nav-pills). But nothing happend.

```
$(".nav-tabs.nav-pills a").click(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

jQuery toggleClass works fine and add 'nav-pills' to 'nav-tabs' element (I checked it in chrome inspector), but alert wont work.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I *really* recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: *"It is important to note that .on() can only create event listeners on elements that **exist at the time you set up the listeners**."* (http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

Comment: Hu Barmar ? This is a strange choice for closing as duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the bind is done once, before the `nav-pills` class is added. So you're binding to an empty set.

You could bind on `".nav-tabs a"` and test in the callback if there's an element in `$(this).closest(".nav-tabs.nav-pills")` but a cleaner solution would be to use `on` and delegation :

```
$(document).on("click", ".nav-tabs.nav-pills a", function(){
```

Comment: Avoid `body` for delegation to avoid any chance of hitting the "0-computed height" bug. Always default to `document`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yes, updated...